# Liferay Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: jsp, liferay

I'm having troubles with a Liferay 5.2 extension system, the problem is that is working in some environments and not in others. In the failing environments it throws these exceptions.

```
23:32:24,363 ERROR [IncludeTag:78] Current URL /web/guest;jsessionid=BFE790BBC107B870740C0268238CEA16 generates exception: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 33 in the jsp file: /html/portlet/ext/courseschedule2/view.jsp
GroupConstants.COMM_CATEGORY_AWR cannot be resolved
30: <%
31: 
32:         if (tabs1.equals("available-AWR")) {
33:             groupCat = GroupConstants.COMM_CATEGORY_AWR;
34:             catTitle = GroupConstants.COMM_CATEGORY_AWR_LABEL;
35:         } else if(tabs1.equals("available-HOT")) {
36:             groupCat = GroupConstants.COMM_CATEGORY_HOT;

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:66)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:2736)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

23:32:27,263 ERROR [IncludeTag:78] Current URL /web/guest;jsessionid=853515070BC187028375B6213F30D246 generates exception: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
23:32:27,268 ERROR [IncludeTag:164] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.html.portlet.ext.courseschedule2.view_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:628)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:149)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:66)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:2736)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
```

The environments have the same Ant, Tomcat and Java installed. I also granted all permissions to my Tomcat directory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Judging that since it is a compile issue and `GroupConstants.COMM_CATEGORY_AWR` is not a standard Liferay constant for `GroupConstants`. I would double check to make sure you are importing the correct `GroupConstants` class and that you have deployed your code correctly.

Comment: Thanks, we actually deploy the system with the same procedure we use in the environments that work, we even get so far as to go for the GroupConstans class and decompile it to make sure the code is there. The import is ok since is working in other machines.